# Definite integral containing log and cot functions

Tags: integration

Consider the following integral

$$c=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(1-x\cot x)\, \mathrm{d}x\approx-3.35333726288947201778500718670823032.$$

I suspect it can be analytically computed because by expanding the $\log$ function, 
$$
c=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1k\int_0^{\pi/2}(x \cot x)^k\, \mathrm{d}x
$$
it can be integrated term by term, albeit in involved form (combination of logarithms and $\zeta$-functions)
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}x \cot x\, \mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2} \pi  \log2,\\
\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2 \cot^2 x\, \mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\pi ^3}{24}+\pi \log2,\\
\int_0^{\pi/2}x^3 \cot^3 x\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\pi^3}{16} (1+2\log 2)+\frac{3 \pi}{16}  (8\log 2+3 \zeta(3)),
$$
and so on.

Just to provide some background to this question, the integral has some significance in theoretical physics. It enters the high-density asymptotics of the quasiparticle renormalization factor of the 3D homogeneous electron gas, see eq. 35 in  Phys. Rev. B 70, 035111 (2004) or eqs. 8 and 9 in Phys. Rev. 120, 2041 (1960):
$$ Z_{qp}=1+\frac{c}{\pi^2}\alpha r_s$$

However, since there is no parametric dependence, and since it is easy to compute numerically, no one cared to find the analytic form. However, I find it is a lovely little problem.

Comment: Why do you suspect this? Have you tried to check?

Comment: @user The integral has some significance in theoretical physics. However, since there is no parametric dependence, and since it is easy to compute numerically, no one cared to find the analytic form. The term-by-term integration can easily be done with e.g. Mathematica. The result is a combination of logarithms and $\zeta$-functions.

Comment: I see no reason to think there is a closed form.

Comment: Since I have not much time left, I set in the log-function $a = 1$ and treat it for any $a$. Now, in general one has to use partial Integration to get rid of the log - function, I would suggest to go this way and use the Limit a->1 at the end. Another way would be differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: @stocha I've tried the partial integration, but it did not bring me further. Differentiation is definitely worth trying.

Comment: @yarchik: In one of my projects I deal with the laplace transform of a complex valued digamma function, in the calculation I meet some integrals with the form of yours using Feymann’s "trick", but also with an addional denominator. That' why I'm interesting in the solution, whenever one exists.

Comment: @yarchik: You can write your integral in the form: $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(\frac{x \cos (x)}{\sin (x)-x \cos (x)}-\frac{x^2 \csc (x)}{\sin (x)-x \cos (x)}\right) \, dx$$, could you please write the expansion?

Comment: @yarchik: I know, if you integrate it seperately. I would like to look to your solution for the expansion, please provide us.

Comment: The complexity of the first coefficients leaves little hope, let alone to find the general term of the expansion.

Comment: @yarchik: I was able to make some progress, your integral is more general as  [Arathoon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565726/integrating-int-0-frac-pi2-x-log-tan-x2n1-dx) or [stocha](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582150/closed-form-of-int-0-frac-pi-2x-left-log-tan-x-right-2n1dx-i). One has to deal with it in the same way.

Comment: @stocha Sounds promising! In the solution of the Arathoon question one makes use of the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} x \tan(x)^n dx$. There is a complementary formula for the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} x^n \cot(x) dx$ in the Table Of Integrals, Series And Products of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik (2007) given by Eq. (3.748.2).

Comment: @yarchik: Thanks for the note :-)

Comment: I don't know how useful this is, but you can reduce your integral to $I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\tan x - x)$ and introducing 2 parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in this fashion: $I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\alpha \tan x - \beta x)$ and then differentiating you find $$\alpha \frac{\partial I}{\partial \alpha}+\beta \frac{\partial I}{\partial \beta}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$But the region of space to solve this PDE in does not look nice...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Alternative expressions for the integral.}}$

Firstly,
$$I = \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\ln(1-x\cot x)\,\mathrm dx
= \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\ln(\sin x - x\cos x)\,\mathrm dx 
- \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\ln(\sin x)\,\mathrm dx = \dfrac\pi2\ln2 +I_1,$$

wherein $I_1$ allows integration by parts:
$$I_1 = \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\ln(\sin x - x\cos x)\,\mathrm dx 
= x\ln(\sin x-x\cos x)\bigg|_{\ 0}^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}
- \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^2\sin x}{\sin x - x\cos x}\,\mathrm dx,$$
$$ I_1 =-\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^2\sin x}{\sin x- x\cos x}\,\mathrm dx
= - \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^2}{1-x\cot x}\,\mathrm dx = - J_{21},\tag1$$
where

> $$J_{mn} = \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^m}{(1-x\cot x)^n}\,\mathrm dx.\tag2$$

On the other hand,
$$J_{21} = \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^2(1-x\cot x + x\cot x)}{1-x\cot x}\,\mathrm dx = \dfrac{\pi^3}{24} + I_2,$$ 
where
$$I_2 = \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^3\cot x}{1 - x\cot x}\,\mathrm dx
=  \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^3}{\tan x - x}\,\mathrm dx.\tag3$$

Formulas $(3)$ are not suitable for numeric calculations.

But integration by parts is possible,
$$I_2 =  \dfrac14\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{1}{\tan x - x}\,\mathrm dx^4
= \dfrac14\dfrac{x^4}{\tan x-x}\bigg|_{\,0}^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}
+ \dfrac14\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^4(1+\tan^2x -1)}{(\tan x - x)^2}\,\mathrm dx,$$
$$ I_2 = \dfrac14\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^4}{(1 - x\cot x)^2}\,\mathrm dx = \dfrac14 J_{42},$$

> $$I = \dfrac\pi2\ln2 - \dfrac{\pi^3}{24} - \dfrac14 J_{42}.\tag4$$

Formula $(4)$ provides both suitable numeric calculations [via Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%2F2%20ln2%20-%20pi%5E3%2F24%20-1%2F4%20int_0%5E%7Bpi%2F2%7D%20x%5E4%20%2F%281%20-%20x%20cot%20x%29%5E2%20dx) by the expression

[image: Expression]

with the result

[image: Result]

and the further building of the series in the elementary functions via the transformations in the form of
$$ J_{42} = \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^4((1 - x\cot x)^2 + 2x\cot x(1 - x\cot x) + x^2\cot^2 x) }{(1 - x\cot x)^2}\,\mathrm dx\\
 = \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\left(x^4 + 2\,\dfrac{x^5\cot x}{1-x\cot x} + \dfrac{x^6\cot^2x}{(1 - x\cot x)^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx\\
 = \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2} x^4\,\mathrm dx
+ \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\left(\dfrac{2x^5\cot x}{1-x\cot x} + \dfrac{x^6\cot^2x}{(1 - x\cot x)^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx,$$
$$J_{42} = \dfrac{\pi^5}{160} + I_3 + I_4,\tag5$$
where
$$I_3 = 2\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^5\cot x}{1-x\cot x} \,\mathrm dx
 = 2\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^5}{\tan x - x}\,\mathrm dx
 = \dfrac13\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{1}{\tan x - x}\,\mathrm dx^6\\
= \dfrac13\dfrac{x^6}{\tan x-x}\bigg|_{\,0}^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}
+ \dfrac13\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^6(1+\tan^2x -1)}{(\tan x - x)^2}\,\mathrm dx = \dfrac13 J_{62},$$
$$I_4 = \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^6\cot^2x}{(1 - x\cot x)^2}\,\mathrm dx
 = \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^6}{(\tan x - x)^2} \,\mathrm dx
 = \dfrac17\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{1}{(\tan x - x)^2} \,\mathrm dx^7\\
= \dfrac27\dfrac{x^7}{(\tan x-x)^3}\bigg|_{\,0}^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}
 + \dfrac27\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^7(1+\tan^2x -1)}{(\tan x - x)^3}\,\mathrm dx
 = \dfrac27\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^7\cot x}{(1 - x\cot x)^3}\,\mathrm dx\\
 = \dfrac27\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^6(1 - (1 - x\cot x))}{(1 - x\cot x)^3}\,\mathrm dx =\dfrac27(J_{63}-J_{62}),$$

Therefore,

> $$I = \dfrac\pi2\ln2 - \dfrac{\pi^3}{24} - \dfrac{\pi^5}{640} - \dfrac1{84}J_{62} -  \dfrac1{14}J_{63}.\tag6$$

Numeric calculations via [Mathcad Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%2F2%20ln2%20-%20pi%5E3%2F24-pi%5E5%2F640%20%20-%201%2F84%20int_0%5E%7Bpi%2F2%7D%20%28x%5E6%2F%281-x%20cot%20x%29%5E2%20%2B%206x%5E6%20%2F%281%20-%20x%20cot%20x%29%5E3%29%20dx) by the formula $(6)$

[image: Formula (6)]

leads to the same result, and this confirms the correctness of the approach.

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Recurrence relations.}}$

For the arbitrary $m,n$
$$ J_{mn} = \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\,(x\cot x + (1-x\cot x))^n \dfrac{x^m}{(1 - x\cot x)^n}\,\mathrm dx
 = \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom nk\dfrac{x^{m+k}\cot^k x}{(1 - x\cot x)^k}\,\mathrm dx
 = \dfrac{\pi^{m+1}}{(m+1)2^{m+1}} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{\dbinom nk}{m+k+1} \int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{\mathrm dx^{m+k+1}}{(\tan x - x)^k}
 = \dfrac{\pi^{m+1}}{(m+1)2^{m+1}}\\
 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{\dbinom nk}{m+k+1} \left(\dfrac{x^{m+k+1}}{(\tan x - x)^{k}}\bigg|_{\,0}^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2} 
+ k\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^{m+k+1}(1+\tan^2x-1)}{(\tan x-x)^{k+1}}\,\mathrm dx\right)\\
 = \dfrac{\pi^{m+1}}{(m+1)2^{m+1}}
 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k}{m+k+1} \dbinom nk
\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^{m+2}(x\cot x)^{k-1}}{(1 -x\cot x)^{k+1}}\,\mathrm dx\\
 = \dfrac{\pi^{m+1}}{(m+1)2^{m+1}}
 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k}{m+k+1} \dbinom nk
\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}\dfrac{x^{m+2}(1-(1-x\cot x))^{k-1}}{(1 -x\cot x)^{k+1}}\,\mathrm dx\\
 = \dfrac{\pi^{m+1}}{(m+1)2^{m+1}}
 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k}{m+k+1} \dbinom nk \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^{k-1-j}\dbinom{k-1}j J_{m+2,\,j+2},$$

> $$J_{mn} = \dfrac{\pi^{m+1}}{(m+1)2^{m+1}}
>  + \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1} F_{j} J_{m+2,\,j+2},\tag7$$

where

> $$F_{j} = \sum\limits_{k=j+1}^n (-1)^{k-1-j} \dfrac{k}{m+k+1}\dbinom nk \dbinom{k-1}j.\tag8 $$

If $(m,n)=(2,1),\ $ then
$$F_{0} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^1 (-1)^{k-1} \dfrac{k}{2+k+1}\dbinom1k \dbinom{k-1}0
=\dfrac14,$$
$$J_{21} = \dfrac{\pi^{3}}{3\cdot2^3} + \sum\limits_{j=0}^0 F_{j} J_{4,\,j+2}
 = \dfrac{\pi^{3}}{24} + J_{42}.$$

If $(m,n)=(4,2),\ $ then
$$F_{0} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^2 (-1)^{k-1} \dfrac{k}{4+k+1}\dbinom2k \dbinom{k-1}0
=\dfrac13 - \dfrac27 = \dfrac{1}{21},$$
$$F_{1} = \sum\limits_{k=2}^2 (-1)^{k} \dfrac{k}{4+k+1}\dbinom2k \dbinom{k-1}1
=\dfrac27,$$
$$J_{42} = \dfrac{\pi^{5}}{5\cdot2^5} + \sum\limits_{j=0}^1 F_{j} J_{2,\,j+2}
 = \dfrac{\pi^5}{160} + \dfrac1{21}J_{62} + \dfrac27J_{63}.$$

[Similarly](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20%7B62.82%2Csum_%28k%3D1%2C2%29%20%28-%28-1%29%5Ek%20*binom%28k-1%2C0%29*%20k%2F%286%2Bk%2B1%29*binom%282%2Ck%29%29%7D%2C%20%7B62.83%2Csum_%28k%3D2%2C2%29%20%28%28-1%29%5Ek%20*binom%28k-1%2C1%29*%20k%2F%286%2Bk%2B1%29*binom%282%2Ck%29%29%7D),
$$J_{62} = \dfrac{\pi^7}{896}+\dfrac1{36}J_{82}+\dfrac29J_{83}\tag9$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha test](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E%28pi%2F2%29%28%28x%5E6-x%5E8%2F36%29%281-x%20cot%20x%29-2x%5E8%2F9%29%2F%281%20-%20x%20cot%20x%29%5E3%20dx%20-%20pi%5E7%2F896)).

[image: J62 Test]

[Besides](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20%7B63.82%2Csum_%28k%3D1%2C3%29%20%28-%28-1%29%5Ek%20*binom%28k-1%2C0%29*%20k%2F%286%2Bk%2B1%29*binom%283%2Ck%29%29%7D%2C%20%7B63.83%2Csum_%28k%3D2%2C3%29%20%28%28-1%29%5Ek%20*binom%28k-1%2C1%29*%20k%2F%286%2Bk%2B1%29*binom%283%2Ck%29%29%7D%2C%20%7B63.84%2Csum_%28k%3D3%2C3%29%20%28-%28-1%29%5Ek%20*binom%28k-1%2C2%29*%20k%2F%286%2Bk%2B1%29*binom%283%2Ck%29%29%7D),
$$J_{63} = \dfrac{\pi^7}{896}+\dfrac1{120}J_{82} + \dfrac1{15}J_{83} + \dfrac3{20}J_{84}.\tag{10}$$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Simple series.}}$

Obtained results are not the best way to get required series of the arbitrary length.

$$\boxed{
\begin{matrix}
I      & = & -3.35333726288947201778500718670823032009876022464933939598 \\
\frac\pi2\ln2 & = &1.088793045151801065250344449118806973669291850184643147162 \\
J_{21} & = & 4.442130308041273083035351635930890531086461245854584994170 \\
\frac{\pi^3}{24} & = & 1.291928195012492507311513127795891466759387023578546153922 \\
J_{42} & = & 12.60080845211512230289535403253999625730829688910415536099 \\
\frac{\pi^5}{160} & = & 1.912623029908009082892133187771472540501879416425468690959 \\
J_{62} & = & 9.357325953756236734147158157553707227832359838953032605558 \\
J_{63} & = & 35.84909465209885681432007993043088180418373451454989791084 \\
\frac{\pi^7}{896} & = & 3.370862977429455432493534032446475258836420173320761453966 \\
J_{82} & = & 13.21743446830609099759197972403428192140938899336281280188 \\
J_{83} & = & 25.28690408493225448274231109747825862030555487117486858192 \\
J_{84} & = & 102.2743092725712233044348622015074565154951081384648503713 \\
\end{matrix}}$$

On the other hand, using of the [simple Laurent series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+35%2F%281-sqrt15+y+cot+%28sqrt15+y%29%29) for the function
$$g(y) = \dfrac{35}{1-y\sqrt{15}\cot y\sqrt{15}} = \dfrac7{y^2}-\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty c_iy^{2i}\tag{11}$$

[image: g(y), Laurent series]

gives evidently convergent series
$$J_{21} = \dfrac1{35}\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi\hspace{-1pt}/_2}
\left(7 - \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty c_i\left(\dfrac{x^2}{15}\right)^{i+1}\right)\,\mathrm dx,$$

> $$J_{21} = \dfrac32\pi - \dfrac3{14}\pi\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \dfrac{c_i}{2i+3}\left(\dfrac{\pi^2}{60}\right)^{i+1}\,\mathrm dx,\tag{12}$$

wherein the first $8$ terms provide the accuracy of $8$ decimal digits.

Comment: Very nice, so you think it is possible to express the integral as a series in $\pi$?

Comment: @yarchik Looks the most perspectve way via recurrence relations for $J.$ But I have not results yet. BTW, 25 our digits are the same, so finite series can not be interesting

Comment: By the way, there should be $-\pi^3/24$ in Eqs.(4,6). It is interesting to observe that your coefficients in front of $\pi^n$ are the same as in $\int_0^{\pi/2} (x\cot x)^n dx$ as shown above.

Comment: @yarchik Wolfram Alpha pictures are correct exactly.

Comment: @yarchik Thanks!)

Comment: @yarchik Recurrence  relations are ready, The further progress looks problematic.

Comment: Don't use $\ln{}$ and $\log{}$ to mean the same thing in the same presentation. Please stick to one!

Comment: @Allawonder Thanks! Fixed in the text.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Could you please pay attention to these 2 questions: 1) Does the derived series converge? It seems not to be the case for $\dfrac{\pi^{m+1}}{(m+1)2^{m+1}}$. 2) How the recursion formula should be evaluated, initialized?

Comment: @yarchik The corresponding paragraph is added to the answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not fully understand where the function $g(y)$ comes from?

Comment: @yarchik Denominator of $J_{21}$ has very simple derivatives,wherein the factors $3&5$ made the expressions hard. The Laurent series can be obtained via the Maclaurin series for  the difference $\frac7{y^2}-g(y),$ see WA link.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Looks very nice!

Comment: @stocha Then I can recommend [very curious](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096523/closed-form-or-an-ode-for-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac1z21z4-fra/2876367#2876367),[very terrible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739358/nested-root-integral-int-01-fracdx-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx/3311446#3311446) and [very estetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3010979/how-to-solve-this-integral-better-way-to-approach/3020134#3020134) integrals.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Looks you have lots of practise with terrible integrals and hope you will also help me in the future with my unsolved problems, not posted yet.

Comment: @stocha You are welcome!

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov By the way in [q-polygamma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483723/closed-form-expression-for-the-finite-sum-sum-k-0n-1-1k-sec-left)
I deal with similar sums as in [very curious,very terrible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096523/closed-form-or-an-ode-for-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac1z21z4-fra/2876367#2876367)
and express them in form of the q-polygamma function.

Comment: @stocha [Interesting integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705505/how-can-i-find-i-n-int-01-frac-x2n-ln-x1-x21x4ndx/3778181#3778181) with the trigamma - function.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov If you have any idea how to express or simplify the finite sum, please let me know!

Answer (score 3):

**Not the answer but too long for a comment** : 
One "ansatz" to find a reformulation of the integral is:

1.) Consider:
$$\mathcal{I}\left( k \right) = \int (x \cot (x))^k \, dx$$
2.) Set $s'(x)=\cot ^k(x)$ and $v(x)=x^k$

3.) Perform partial integration:
$$\int \frac{\partial (s(x) v(x))}{\partial x} \, dx=\int v(x) s'(x) \
\, dx+\int s(x) v'(x) \, dx$$ to reduce the power of $v(x)=x^k$

4.) For $$\mathcal{J}\left( k \right) =\int \cot ^k(x) \, dx$$ use [Tunk-Fey](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837337/if-i-n-int-cotnx-dx-then-i-0-i-1-2i-2i-3-cdots-i-8-i-9i-10/837355#837355) to reduce the k-power under the integral.

5.) Collect the resulting terms … $-\frac{\cot ^{n-1}(x)}{n-1}$ to an infinity sum.

6.) Use for the expression:

$$ \int (x^{p} (\sum_{k} ...+...\int(\cot (y))^p\, dy)) \, dx$$ the formula 
in the Table Of Integrals, Series And Products of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik (2007) given by Eq. (3.748.2).

**Edit** : I validated it numerically for the sum over k=1...2 and it worked!

Comment: Thanks for outlining the program to attack problem. So its seems the integral can be integrated term-by-term which makes it feasible to represent in terms of series.